# Is Darth Vader Going to Appear in the Upcoming Star Wars Rebels Series?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

Does anyone know if **Darth Vader** is going to play a prominent role in the upcoming series of [Star Wars Rebels](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Rebels) or is the character going to be on the sidelines?

I've been trying to get some info on the story because I love the animated show!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE #4**

Yes, he did make an appearance, in the very first episode no less.

The series' Executive Producer spoke about this in an interview with IGN.

> *"We wanted to do something special for the ABC broadcast,"* Executive Producer Dave Filoni said. *"We've added a scene which gives audiences
>   insight into the Inquisitor and **includes a cameo by Darth Vader voiced
>   by the distinguished actor James Earl Jones."***

---

**UPDATE  #5**
Based on the [season #2 trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Av8GjpGK98A), we'll be seeing **a lot more** of him...

---

<s>Despite the lack of a canon confirmation, it's now looking almost certain that Darth Vader will be make at least a cameo appearance in the [Star Wars Rebels](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Rebels) series</s>

Most tellingly, Hasbro has [leaked](http://makingstarwars.net/2014/01/it-looks-like-darth-vader-might-be-in-star-wars-rebels/) a list of "Rebels" branded masks that will be released later this year. Darth Vader is among them.

> Now kids can become their favorite STAR WARS characters, as well as
>   new heroes and villains from the new animated series STAR WARS REBELS
>   with these role-play masks, each featuring authentic styling! Choose
>   from characters like **DARTH VADER,** STORMTROOPER, EZRA, and the
>   INQUISITOR, each sold separately.

The [PR blurb](http://makingstarwars.net/2014/08/new-evidence-darth-vader-may-star-wars-rebels/) for the mask is a dead giveaway:

> *Want to feel just like your favorite Star Wars villain? Then strap on this incredible mask and battle the Rebels, **just like the sinister
>   Darth Vader from Star Wars Rebels!** You’ll be the Dark Lord of the
>   neighborhood when you battle in your Darth Vader mask!*

[image]

**UPDATE #1** 
 -  Disney has released their upcoming "[brand strategy](http://www.jedinews.co.uk/popup.aspx?imgpath=/images/news/articles/ep7_brandlicensing_2.jpg&pageTitle=Star%20Wars)" documents which include a mention that there will be "***Darth Vader Themed TV Specials***" in Spring/Summer 2014. 
Unless there's another suprise in the offing, this coincides with the release of SW:Rebels.

[image: Disney brand strategy document]

**UPDATE #2** 
- In a recent interview At [NY ComicCon](http://starwars.com/news/nycc-2013-meet-the-inquisitor-the-new-face-of-evil-in-star-wars-rebels.html), Showrunner Dave Filoni indicated that the main baddie of the series (known as 'The Inquisitor') would be...

> "***personally*** tasked by Darth Vader to hunt down the remaining
>   Jedi Knights"

The clear implication is that a cameo appearance will be made in the first episode, with infrequent appearances in later shows (so as not to overshadow their new villain)

**UPDATE #3**
In an interview for [USA Today](http://www.usatoday.com/story/life/tv/2014/09/30/star-wars-rebels-preview/16463105/), Executive producer Dave Filoni spoke about his desire to have at least a cameo from Vader:

> Still, Filoni wouldn't mind getting James Earl Jones into a recording
>   studio and bringing him back to the Dark Side.
>
> "***We have a nice history of honoring the great legacy characters***,"
>   Filoni teases. "***It would be a shame never to have Darth Vader in the
>   show, I'll say that much.***"

Comment: Excellent, i hope we get to see Darth V, i'm interested in the way he will be animated, in the Films he was a bit Static not performing any Jedi Acrobatics due to technological barriers. Only Luke did a few backflips because he was young and able. So now with all the great Animation Clone Wars has shown, i hope wee see some amazing creativity and character animation with Darth V. Cant Wait.

Comment: @Tasos - Yes, in the original films he was decidedly lumbering and clumsy. It's been pointed out on more than one occasion that his lightsaber technique should have merited him almost instant death against a competent swordsman.

Comment: Yes i saw the extended version of the 1st episode featuring a small clip with DV. We see in future episodes if he is seen in larger parts. He must get involved with something in the series, he cant be sitting in his office all day making phone calls and  giving orders. :))

Answer (score 1):

Dave Filoni hinted that it might come to that if, the Rebels make enough vibrations in the spider web that is the empire, to attract the attention of Vader and the Emperor. Basically he's saying that if the show runs like Clone Wars, they will appear at some point.

Comment: Yeah it looks good so far, i like the new animation styles and by season 2 the stories will get better and the show more established like clone wars.